# Cannot convert one 3d matrix to another

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unordered-map

I have a function `SARavesphnp()` defined as type:

`std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::unordered_map<unsigned, double>>>;`

However, when I try and return a variable of the same type, I get this error:

`error: could not convert '(mat3d (*)[(long int)y2][(long int)z2])(& SARave)' from 'mat3d (*)[(long int)y2][(long int)z2] {aka std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::unordered_map<unsigned int, double> > > (*)[(long int)y2][(long int)z2]}' to 'mat3d {aka std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::unordered_map<unsigned int, double> > >}'`

This is my code:

```
#include <unordered_map>

using mat3d = std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::unordered_map<unsigned, double>>>;

mat3d foo(const int, const int, const int);

int main()
{

    foo(10, 10, 10);

    return 0;
}

mat3d foo(const int x2, const int y2, const int z2)
{
    mat3d SARave[x2][y2][z2];

    return SARave;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your goal here in terms of usage?

Comment: mat3d SARave[x2][y2][z2]; <-- this line is obviously wrong, since [][][] would be for accessing mat3d, and not for declaring an instance of it.

Comment: Why are you using an unordered map for this???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: I'm using an unordered_map to create a 3d matrix to store information from a file, and this file specifies an index, and a value. So I use the index on a line and read the 4th value into the matrix. However, the index doesn't start from 0, and it jumps around. Here's an example from the file:

    33 78 283 300.33898330722
    33 78 284 301.00267378042

So since I'll be jumping around the index of the matrix, I used an unordered_map because it fills in the blanks with 0s.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Works for me under gcc-4.7.

```
mat3d foo(const int x2, const int y2, const int z2)
{
    mat3d SARave;
    SARave[x2][y2][z2] = 0.;

    return SARave;
}
```

There was nothing wrong with the types. This line `mat3d SARave[x2][y2][z2];`, however, did not initialize a variable but instead declared a function that returns a mat3d. I'm sorry, I can't explain exactly why right now but the `»mat3d (*)[(long ...` part in the error message indicates that the compiler tries to convert a function pointer to the mat3d object, which obviously fails.